# php arrays add value from one array to another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have 2 arrays, both generated from separate mysql queries as shown below:

ARRAY 1

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => black
        [hex_colour] => #000000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => blue
        [hex_colour] => #4e5f98
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => brown
        [hex_colour] => #a3775e
    )
```

ARRAY 2

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => black
        [count] => 122
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => blue
        [count] => 33
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => brown
        [count] => 5
    )
```

My question is how do I add [count] to ARRAY 1 so the result would be:

New ARRAY

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => black
        [hex_colour] => #000000
        [count] => 122
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => blue
        [hex_colour] => #4e5f98
        [count] => 33
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => brown
        [hex_colour] => #a3775e
        [count] => 5

    )
```

I apologise I haven't got examples of code that I've tried, but I have searched google using a number of different search terms but with no luck. Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: array_merge () ..?

Comment: Are they always in the same order? Is [0] in array1 == [0] in array2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fullfillment your requirement.

```
$arrayName1[0] = array(
        'value' => "black",
        'hex_colour' => "#000000",
    );
    $arrayName1[1] = array(
        'value' => "blue",
        'hex_colour' => "#4e5f98",
    );
    $arrayName1[2] = array(
        'value' => "brown",
        'hex_colour' => "#a3775e",
    );

    $arrayName2[0] = array(
        'value' => "black",
        'count' => "122",
    );
    $arrayName2[1] = array(
        'value' => "blue",
        'count' => "33",
    );
    $arrayName2[2] = array(
        'value' => "brown",
        'count' => "5",
    );

    foreach ($arrayName1 as $key => $row1) {
        foreach ($arrayName2 as $key => $row2) {
            if($row1['value'] == $row2['value'] ){
                $row1['count'] = $row2['count'];
                $data[] = $row1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In `$data` you got same array as mentioned in your quetions.
If you have any doubt, please comment below.

Comment: Hi Jaimin, thank you it works as does Deepak's above.

Answer (score 4):

```
$data= Array(
    'value' => 'black',
   'hex_colour' => '#000000'
);
$data1= Array(
    'value' => 'black',
   'count' => '122'
);


print_r(array_merge($data1, $data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$count_array=[];

foreach($array2 as $count)
{
    $count_array[$count['value']]=$count['count'];
}
$final=[];
foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    $final=[
             "value"=>$value['value'],
             "hex_colour"=>$value['hex_colour'],
             "count"=>$count_array[$value['value']]
        ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code-

```
  $array1= array(
    'value' => 'black',
   'hex_colour' => '#000000'
);
$array2= array(
    'value' => 'black',
   'count' => '122'
);

$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

For reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php